# Joomla Module with Installing Table Not Working

Tags: joomla

i am new in joomla development, i am making a form as a module in joomla, i want store data in database with this form, its basically registration type which is totally separate from joomla user. but at installation time this module doesn't create tables in database, i used both methods installing from zip and discover and installed

this is my directory structure

[image]

my xml manifest is

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<extension  type="module" client="site" method="install" version="3.0">
    <name>Registration Form</name>
    <author>Arsalan</author>
    <creationDate>9,OCT,2014</creationDate>
    <version>1.0.0</version>
    <description>This is registration form which will display on homepage </description>
    <files>
        <filename module="mod_registrationform">mod_registrationform.php</filename>
        <filename>mod_registrationform.xml</filename>
        <filename>helper.php</filename>
        <folder>tmpl</folder>
        <folder>sql</folder> 
    </files>
    <install>
        <sql>
            <file driver="mysql" charset="utf8">sql/install.sql</file>
        </sql>
    </install>
    <update>
        <sql>
            <file driver="mysql">sql/install.sql</file>
        </sql>
    </update>
    <uninstall>
        <sql>
            <file driver="mysql" charset="utf8">sql/uninstall.sql</file>
        </sql>
    </uninstall>

    <update> 
        <schemas>
            <schemapath type="mysql">sql/updates</schemapath> 
        </schemas> 
    </update>
</extension>
```

this is sql code which is working fine

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `#__helloworld` (
        `id` int(10) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
        `hello` text NOT NULL,
        `lang` varchar(25) NOT NULL,

  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 AUTO_INCREMENT=1;
```

i am tired of searching this problem solution, please help me thanks : )

Comment: i have also tried with install and update method in extension tag but i am failed, i think i fulfilled all the requirement, but its not working i am stuck and upset : (

Comment: Can you please let me know what error you are getting when installing it??

Comment: its not creating tables in database, i have set this module on theme position to show dummy output, its fine

Comment: I have just tried installing module with same xml you provided in question. and it is creating table. So your xml is fine.. are you using joomla 3?

Comment: yup i am using joomla 3.3, and i am developing it on local host, and i have permission to create tables. can you please provide source you have created

Comment: Download it from [here](https://www.zipshare.com/download/eyJhcmNoaXZlSWQiOiI3ZjQ4MGNjNC04Y2M5LTQ1MmItOThmMi05OGUyOTAwNDcxNmYiLCJlbWFpbCI6ImRqb2huOTU4NzBAZ21haWwuY29tIn0=) it is a dummy module

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/62674/discussion-between-rahul-k-and-arsalan-sheikh).

Comment: Just to let you know, you should be using `method="upgrade"`, not `method="install"`